# Drawing a rectangle to the screen

Tags: c, windows, drawing

Is there a way to make the resulting rectangle from the FillRect() function stay on the screen? I am calling this function but it only remains up on the screen for a fraction of a second before disappearing. The only way to keep it on the screen is to run this in a while (true) loop which seems very inefficient.

```
void DrawRect(int x, int y, int w, int h, HBRUSH brushColor)
{
   RECT rect = { x, y, x + w, y + h };
   FillRect(HDC_Desktop, &rect, brushColor);
}
```

I have to ask what makes the resulting box from this function disappear? I notice it still sometimes flashes even when ran inside a while (true) loop. Does it disappear when your monitor refreshes or is disappearing not inherent to this function? My goal is to make a rectangle that stays on the screen for a set amount of time. Whether that be me setting a time period for it to last or having to manually delete it but either way running a while (true) loop to continuously print a rectangle to my screen is terribly inefficient.

Comment: The normal way would be to draw it when you get a `WM_PAINT` message, but as you don't own the desktop you're not going to get messages for it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Is there another way to do it if I can't get the WM_PAINT message? What causes the box to instantly disappear? Anyways around this?

Comment: The rectangle disappears after one frame because the display receives a redraw event which causes it to write pixels over where your rectangle was before. This happens unless, as you saw before, you use a loop to continuously redraw the rectangle.

Comment: @SafelyFast Alright so I assume I could draw the rectangle at the same frame rate but that would probably cause a lot of flashing. Do you have any other suggestions for drawing to the screen besides from FillRect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not paint directly on the screen DC! This has not worked properly since Vista (DWM) and even before that it was not a great thing to do.

You should create a window with the `WS_POPUP` style and draw there when you get the `WM_PAINT` message (don't forget to call `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint`)...

Comment: Oh thank you! Do you know how I can get the process ID from the HWND object?

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId

Comment: Do you have any idea why the box might be flashing? I only drew it once to the transparent screen but there is a slight flicker to it any thoughts on why?